# My iPad App Will Include a Twitter Widget. Will Apple or Twitter Have Issues With This Usage?

Tags: iphone, ipad, twitter

For the iPad imaging app I am writing I have include the ability to email a friend or send a Twitter tweet for world-of-mouth marketing. Here is what my Twitter widget currently looks like:

[alt text http://www.daturner.com/stackoverflow/screendumps/twitter-widget-screendump.png](http://www.daturner.com/stackoverflow/screendumps/twitter-widget-screendump.png)

Am I asking for trouble by using the Twitter logo in this manner? Will this send up a red flag in the Apple app approval process?

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: This is not a programming-related question, but one about acceptable use of a logo.

Comment: Dude. Chill. I am asking a friggin' question about my app. Do you have an answer? No? Then move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try checking out Twitter's guidelines for their logo:
http://help.twitter.com/entries/77641-guidelines-for-use-of-the-twitter-trademark

Especially the section reading:

> **Merchandise/Manufactured Items**
>   Please
>   note that we generally don’t permit
>   use of our marks on merchandise.
>
> Do: Contact us at trademarks at
>   twitter.com with a detailed proposal
>   if you would like to request an
>   exception.